# Dynamic allocation of nested vectors

Tags: c++

I did something like:

```
Grid(int row, int col):num_of_row_(row), num_of_col_(col) {
     grid_ = new vector<vector<bool> > (row, col);  
}
```

which dynamically allocates nested vector. Is this correct? I mean using this syntax:

```
new vector<vector<type> > (outersize, innersize)
```

where ** outersize, innersize are both "int" variables.**

update:
I actually used this code, and it works. I just want to find out why.

Comment: Beware vector<bool> may not be what you think it is on some implementations.  And I don't think this is correct, but I haven't done it in a while so I'll let others more knowledgable in this than I answer definitively...

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: vector is a dynamic container. That means, it will resize itself according to what you're feeding it. A 'new' is unnecessary in this context. Are you actually looking for `new bool[outer][inner];`?

Comment: I believe the correct way to format this is `vector< vector<type> > vec(size, vector<type>(size));

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: Not true.  `std::vector<int> v; v[1] = 2;` is Undefined Behavior, not an automatic resize.

Comment: The question is, why "new" at all? Do you really need it on the heap?

Comment: "I actually used this code, and it works. I just want to find out why." I do not see how your code would work: [take a look at this link](http://ideone.com/4Hop2v), it produces a compile error on ideone.

Comment: @aschepler I agree with you, that your example does produce glibberish, but that's not 'the way you use it' either. If it was a map, that code would work just fine, because the index is 'the key', while in a vector, the underlying container is actually a dynamic list. (which resizes according to what you're 'pushing' and 'popping'). But that's besides the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter passed to the constructor is the element of the vector to be repeated `outersize` times. You should use this syntax:

```
new vector<vector<type> > (outersize, vector<type>(innersize, elementValue));
```

For example, to make a 50x25 grid of `bool` initially set to `true`, use:

```
vector<vector<bool> > *grid = new vector<vector<bool> >(50, vector<bool>(25, true));
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. But in this case, I need innersize, outersize both be variables.

Comment: @AlanShore That's perfectly fine, they do not need to be constants. Arguably, that's the biggest advantage of vectors over built-in arrays.

Comment: Thanks but I tried variables. And it gives me the this error: ‘row’ cannot appear in a constant-expression

Comment: @AlanShore I don't think it should: here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/rT4XqE) when I use variables.

Comment: But I still wonder why my code actually works. Could you try to explain that?

Comment: @AlanShore This is rather surprising. What compiler / standard library do you use? It looks like the compiler can initialize a vector of booleans from an integer. There is indeed a constructor that takes a single `int`, but the compiler shouldn't be able to use that constructor implicitly.

Comment: yeah. It's quite weird how my code could work. I used g++ on a Mac.